# Pure JSP without mixing HTML, by writing html as Java-like code

Tags: java, html, jsp

**Please read before answering.** This is a **fantasy** programming technique I'm dreaming up. I want to know if there's anything close in real life.

The following JSP page:

```
<%
html {
    head {
        title {"Pure fantasy";}
    }
    body {
        h1 {"A heading with double quote (\") character";}
        p {"a paragraph";}
        String s = "a paragraph in string. the date is ";
        p {
            s;
            new Date().toString();
        }
        table (Border.ZERO, new Padding(27)) {
            tr {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    td {i;}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
%>
```

could generate the following HTML page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pure fantasy</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>A heading with double quote (") character</h1>
        <p>a paragraph</p>
        <p>a paragraph in string. the date is 11 December 2012</p>
        <table border="0" padding="27">
            <tr>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The thing about this fantasy is it reuses the same old Java programming language technique that enable customized keywords used in a way similar to `if-else-then`, `while`, `try-catch` etc to represent html tags in a non-html way that can easily be checked for syntactic correctness, and **most importantly** can easily be mixed up with regular Java code without being lost in a sea of `<%`, `%>`, `<%=`, `out.write()`, etc.

An added feature is that strings can directly be placed as commands to print out into generated HTML, something Java doesn't support (where pure strings have to be assigned to variables before use).

- Is there anything in real life that comes close?
- If not, is it possible to define customized keywords in Java or JSP?
- Or do I have to create an entirely new programming language for that?
- What problems do you see with this kind of setup?

**PS:** I know you can use HTML libraries to construct HTML using Java code, but the problem with such libraries is, the source code itself doesn't have a readable HTML representation like the code above does - if you get what I mean.

Comment: Congrats, you've reinvented PHP, more or less.

Comment: Take a look at - http://www.playframework.org/modules/rythm

Comment: Wow I was expecting a lot of -1 :) @TomG guess that explains what's so different about PHP, but what I really want is to see JSP extended to remove dependency on mixing HTML (not switch to PHP :) ). AVD, thanks, seriously no clue what anything there is, including Play!, Rythm, Japid or Jamon...

Comment: Alright, now your question makes no sense.  You say you don't want to mix code and HTML, but that's exactly what your example shows.  You say you want a cleaner way to create HTML, but your example is just as messy as what you describe.  A pure way of creating the document by editing the DOM is too verbose for you.  Please clarify.

Comment: @Brad perhaps you can show me a short sample on how I can "create the document by editing the DOM" because I think we're just having a misunderstanding here. Please post as answer.

Comment: @ADTC, I did post that as an answer... you said that you already tried it, and it was too verbose, so I deleted it.

Comment: You didn't provide any sample, just a link. And what I tried doesn't sound like what you're referring to. Which is why I asked for a sample code block so we can clear our misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's from the Ruby world, not Java, but take a look at [Haml](http://haml.info).

Comment: OMG that's beautiful.... :) It will be nice if you extended your answer with the example from the homepage or something more :)

Comment: I believe there's a [Java implementation of HAML](https://github.com/raymyers/JHaml).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're basically asking for an alternative HTML templating engine.  There are plenty of options if you google for that.  The one that appears to come up quite frequently (for Java) is [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/).  One example from the [user guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html) looks like:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
Hello $customer.Name!
<table>
#foreach( $mud in $mudsOnSpecial )
   #if ( $customer.hasPurchased($mud) )
      <tr>
        <td>
          $flogger.getPromo( $mud )
        </td>
      </tr>
   #end
#end
</table>
```